# What is the formula for $(x_1 - x_2 - ... - x_n)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am curious about formulas for 
$(x_1 - x_2 - ... - x_n)^2$ and $(x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n)^2$
Also for $(x_1 - x_2 - ... - x_n)^3$ and $(x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n)^3$

Are there any formulas where we have mixed + and - inside the brackets? also are there any formula for the general case where power is $n$?

I do not know the name of these expressions and thus I could not find it in Google ... I am sorry if my question is silly.

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: @whatever THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Here you find the formula which covers all your cases

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem.

Since the $x_i$, $i=1, ..., m$ in the mentioned theorem can be negative as well you do not have to distinguish between $+$ and $-$ inside the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n)^2 = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_n^2 + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=i+1}^n x_i x_j$$